# Iam not getting the background color of recyclerview item by button clicks outside of the recyclerview.?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
package com.android_examples.recyclerview_android_examplescom;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayout relativeLayout;
    Button button;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recylerViewLayoutManager;
    String[] subjects =
            {
            "ANDROID",
            "PHP",
            "BLOGGER",
            "WORDPRESS",
            "JOOMLA",
            "ASP.NET",
            "JAVA",
            "C++",
            "MATHS",
            "HINDI",
            "ENGLISH"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recylerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recylerViewLayoutManager);

        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context, subjects);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recylerViewLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(10).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.android_examples.recyclerview_android_examplescom.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerAdapter:--

```
package com.android_examples.recyclerview_android_examplescom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    String[] SubjectValues;
    Context context;
    View view1;
    ViewHolder viewHolder1;
    TextView textView;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context1,String[] SubjectValues1){

        SubjectValues = SubjectValues1;
        context = context1;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v){

            super(v);

            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.subject_textview);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items,parent,false);

        viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);

        return viewHolder1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
package com.android_examples.recyclerview_android_examplescom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    String[] SubjectValues;
    Context context;
    View view1;
    ViewHolder viewHolder1;
    TextView textView;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context1,String[] SubjectValues1){

        SubjectValues = SubjectValues1;
        context = context1;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v){

            super(v);

            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.subject_textview);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items,parent,false);

        viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);

        return viewHolder1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){

        holder.textView.setText(SubjectValues[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){

        return SubjectValues.length;
    }
}
    holder.textView.setText(SubjectValues[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){

    return SubjectValues.length;
}
```

}

If i want to change the background of perticular item in Recyclerview from button click it will effect to only visible items only not for invisible means (first item is visible to user it will effect, but for last item it will not change the color )

Please Help me...

Thanks In advance..

Answer (score 0):

First get the click action of convertView (Object of View) under this set view as

```
if(!convertView.isSelected()){
convertView.setSelected(true);
//here change the background color as selected.
}else{
convertView.setSelected(false);
//here change the background color as unselected.
}
```

Handel isSelected status in selection.

How to get the convertView Object reference

Comment: Your updated code is not correct. Please correct and to set background of item use: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.itemView.isSelected()){
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
                }else {
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

`OnItemClickListener`  Will give you the position of the view and you can use this below code for changing background of selected positioned row

```
private View SelectedItem;

private void BackColor(View view) {
 if (SelectedItem != null) {
    SelectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 }
 view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
SelectedItem = view;

}
yourListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

{
 @Override
 public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapterView, View view,int i, long l){
    BackColor(view);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sir, Actually i am not getting what you sent, I updated the Question please check that one and recomment...